# Board Game Separation Lines Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, format

i'm fairly new to python, I am currently trying to create a game board with borders. so far i have:

```
for row in range(5):
print('-'*50)
for col in range(5):
    print('| {:<5}{:<3}'.format(row, col), end = '')
print()
```

Which gives me:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| 0    0  | 0    1  | 0    2  | 0    3  | 0    4  
--------------------------------------------------
| 1    0  | 1    1  | 1    2  | 1    3  | 1    4  
--------------------------------------------------
| 2    0  | 2    1  | 2    2  | 2    3  | 2    4  
--------------------------------------------------
| 3    0  | 3    1  | 3    2  | 3    3  | 3    4  
--------------------------------------------------
| 4    0  | 4    1  | 4    2  | 4    3  | 4    4
```

My problem is that there isn't a line at the end of the rows and there isn't a dotted line under the last row. When I type  end = '|' I get a line at the end but also double lines in the middle like:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| 0    0  || 0    1  || 0    2  || 0    3  || 0    4  |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1    0  || 1    1  || 1    2  || 1    3  || 1    4  |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2    0  || 2    1  || 2    2  || 2    3  || 2    4  |
--------------------------------------------------
| 3    0  || 3    1  || 3    2  || 3    3  || 3    4  |
--------------------------------------------------
| 4    0  || 4    1  || 4    2  || 4    3  || 4    4  |
```

I don't have clue on how to ad the last dotted line.

What do I have to do to get a single line at both ends and in between?
How do I get a dotted line under the last row?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this specific format using the following code:

```
for row in range(5):
    print('\n' + '-'*50, end = "\n|")
    for col in range(5):
        print(' {:<5}{:<3}'.format(row, col), end = '|', sep="|")
print('\n' + '-'*50)
```

Output:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| 0    0  | 0    1  | 0    2  | 0    3  | 0    4  |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1    0  | 1    1  | 1    2  | 1    3  | 1    4  |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2    0  | 2    1  | 2    2  | 2    3  | 2    4  |
--------------------------------------------------
| 3    0  | 3    1  | 3    2  | 3    3  | 3    4  |
--------------------------------------------------
| 4    0  | 4    1  | 4    2  | 4    3  | 4    4  |
--------------------------------------------------
```